# Passing optional parameter in typescript when setting cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, caching, mongoose

I am setting some values in cache using cache-manager & mongoose-cache-manager npm module.

```
public setCache(key:string, value:string, options?:SomeType) {
   this.set(key,value,options); 
}

interface SomeType {
   ttl?:number 
}
```

So I have two scenarios where I need to pass options & I donot need to pass options.

```
Scenario 1: setCache('key', value, {ttl: 3600});
Scenario 2: setCache('key2', value2);
```

I am using both scenarios. But where I am getting stuck is like, If user doesn't pass options params (Scenario2) what will be the effect? Inorder to make both scenarios work together what can I do? Do I need to pass default as undefined in setCache function defenition?

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Set a default value for options parameter, so if user don't pass it use the default value

```
public setCache(key:string, value:string, options:SomeType={ttl:3600}) {
   this.set(key,value,options); 
}
```

Comment: As per the documentation, we have already setting default value fot ttl if user doesn't provide any options. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cache-manager#single-store .

Comment: As per their docs, ttl is optional, so if you don't pass ttl, it will set it's default value. nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Yes but i am using redis cache also. So their ttl is different, mongoose cache ttl is different. So how can i pass default value in set cache method?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default values in typescript.
eg:
    options:SomeType={ttl:2000}